# JQUERY - HTML select element does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready()(function(){
    var selArr = [
        {val: 'corsair', text: 'Corsair'},
        {val: 'evga', text: 'EVGA'},
        {val: 'antec', text: 'Antec'}
    ];

    $('#pSupply').append('<select id="psuSel" />').promise().done(function(){
    $(selArr).each(function(){
        $('#psuSel').append($('<option />').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    });
  });
});
```

The code above is what I am trying to use for a sort of dynamically generated select with option.Unfortunately this does not display the select menu at all.

Comment: You have a type in your DOM ready handler, fixing that makes it work -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/61kwjkka/

Comment: Note that `append` is synchronous, and doesn't need a promise or a callback at all.

Comment: @adeneo thank you, don't know how I managed to overlook that haha, great stuff though

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding to the document ready event at all, nor calling your function, because you've written this:

```
$(document).ready()( ... );
                 ^^
```

You call the `$(document).ready()` function then, separately, declare a function wrapped in brackets, and never execute it nor pass it to something that would execute it. It certainly doesn't get passed to the `ready()` function. I'd wager if you added a `console.log("function's running");` statement to the beginning of your function, you'd never see that message in the console.

Try removing those `()`'s:

```
$(document).ready( ... );
```

---

Note: calling `.ready()` with a blank argument [isn't a valid use of that function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score -1):

there is error in your code 
tyr this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var selArr = [
    {val: 'corsair', text: 'Corsair'},
    {val: 'evga', text: 'EVGA'},
    {val: 'antec', text: 'Antec'}
];

$('#pSupply').append('<select id="psuSel" />').promise().done(function(){
$(selArr).each(function(){
    $('#psuSel').append($('<option />').attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
});
});
});
```

$(document).ready() is predefined function and will call once page is ready with content, so if user want to execute certain code after page load, user must override ready() by passing function as argument to it.

Comment: You should describe what the error is, and what you've changed in the code to address it.

Comment: slight mistake
     
    "$(document).ready()(function(){"
should be

    "$(document).ready(function(){"

Comment: I recommend that you update your answer to explain the problem, then I'll be happy to reverse my vote.